# Serial TX and RX requirements

Tags: pcb-design, serial, esp32, routing, cp2102

I am building a custom ESP32 PCB.
What do I need to take into account to route the serial tracks (Rx Tx)?

Are they differential pairs?
Can they be routed under an SMD resistor?
Is 0.250mm (9.8 mil) enough?
Do they need a GND plane bellow for the return current?

This is my schema ([full project](https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/tree/main/PCB/schematics-v16-espinside)):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree with jp314. But make sure your schematic is correct. Usually for micro-to-micro you need to connect RX to TX and vice versa. But sometimes with other devices you need to connect RX to RX and TX to TX. So double-check the datasheet for the parts you are using.

Comment: Pretty sure your schematic is correct in this case, though. Just be careful if you ever use a GSM chip or even a GPS.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mkeith! I thouth it was always crossed. I will double check for the ESP32 (and the future ones! :)

Comment: As an aside, use a ground symbol for ground, not a label. Where possible have them point down. This is a convention not a rule. The label GND(5V) i find is confusing. You’ll also used polarised capacitor symbols for non- polarised parts. Again, confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips @Kartman!! I will correct that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not differential signals and don't need extreme care. They can route under a R, don't need a GND plane, and don't need any particular width (impedance).